# Mouseover my title in xaml

Tags: xaml, tooltip, wpftoolkit

Hi all i'm new to this xaml code so excuse me if.i ask some stupid question. 
I have a title call conference with hyperlink that take you to conference paye and inside that conference page i have link and table in it.. All I want to so is to create à tooltip that will show the link and some info when the mouse is over it

Comment: Thanks Matt but i've done that already..  but all I want is.. In my home page i have à table with 20 link each header has is link to his own page..  All I want is.. When u point à mouse on header i want the page inside the header to popup with out clicking on it..  not sure if i made myself clear..  thanks again for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most elements in XAML have a `ToolTip` that you can set in XAML. Tool tips are automatically shown when the mouse hovers of the lement. You didn't specify what type of element your title is, but for this example I will use a `Label`.

To specify a ToolTip, set up your element like this:

```
<Label>
     <Label.ToolTip>
         <!-- put the elements you want in the tool tip in here -->
     </Label.ToolTip>
</Label>
```

Hope this helps put you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

```
   <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource LabelRequiredStyle}" Content="{Binding Value}", ToolTip="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
```

Set this attribute to the lable and replace 'Value' with the value of content of Label.

Comment: hi Thanks for the answer 
i have just another question to ask
instead of me trying to get like iframe in xaml , i just  want now to display the input on page2 into my tooltip Inside my index page
for example in my index page i have my title (detail1,detail2) all i want is when i put the mouse on detail1, i want all the information in detail to show up in tooltip and the same for detail 2 so on..

Comment: i can't understand your requirement clearly MK. Please elaborate clearly.

Comment: thanks for your respond and sorry for not making myself clear 
ok 3 pages Index.xaml, Index.cs,Index.XML
Inside my index.xaml i have a table with several of rows, each row contain a title,which is link to anothe page.xaml. at the moment in order for the user to see what Inside the table he or she need to click on the title and what i would like to do is to display a the information of each title when the mouse is over it and display in tooltip or richtooltip or etc.